# Multidimensional array with many sub arrays? how to use foreach in value [B] to print values in frontend

Tags: php, magento, multidimensional-array

Using Webservices I receive a reply in the following format:

```
Array
(
[Data] => Array
    (
        [A] => Array
            (
                [B] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [C] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => some value1
                                    )
                                [D] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => some value2
                                    )
                                [E] => some value3
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [C] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => some value4
                                    )
                                [D] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => some value5
                                    )
                                [E] => 5
                            )
                    )
                [value] =>
```

using magento as php framework i create a controller displaying the following information

```
    public function bynumberAction(){
        $t = new \RocketShipIt\Track('fedex');
        $response = $t->track('770190256519');

//        parse results
        $events['C'] = $response['A']['B']['C'];
        $events['D'] = $response['A']['B']['D']
        $events['E'] = $response['A']['B']['E']

//        serve results
        $this->loadLayout( array('default','shipping_track_bynumber'));
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('track_bynumber')
                ->setCollection($events)
                ->setTemplate('shipping/track/bynumber.phtml');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

On the frontend phtml (bynumber.phtml) file I put:

```
<?php $res = $this->getCollection() ?>

<?php foreach ($res as $row) {echo $row['C'] . ' ' . $row['D'] . ' ' . $row['E'] . '<br />';} ?>
```

No information is displayed.. any help appreciated. brgds

Comment: `foreach($res['A']['B'] as $row) { ...`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn thanks for the comment, I tested your proposed solution but it didnt display the information. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more issues. First of all, there is a syntax error - missing semicolon after a command on lines 6 and 7 of function `bynumberAction`.

Second: why do you have different array structure in your controller, if you know how the response looks?

You use:
`$response['A']['B']['C'];`

Response looks:
`$response['Data']['A']['B']['0']['C'];`

Try this in your controller:

```
$events = array()
foreach ($response['Data']['A']['B'] as $data)
{
    $events[] = $data;
}
```

...and in a template:

```
foreach ($res as $row) { echo $row['C']['value'] ... }
```

Comment: my main idea is to display all responses based on B. If I placed response ['0'] only will return the first array.

Comment: Of course, but an array under key 'B' doesn't contain key 'C', so how would you use it?

Comment: @s_h Try `var_dump($events)` on last line of function `bynumberAction`. You will see how that array looks and you should understand how it works. It's really easy. Especially if it's formatted as in your question. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

At first sight you missed a depth there:

Instead of `$events['C'] = $response['A']['B']['C'];` you should have `$events['C'] = $response['A']['B'][0]['C'];` or `$events['C'] = $response['A']['B'][1]['C'];` or make a loop, depends what you want.

Comment: my main idea is to display all responses based on B. If I placed response ['0'] only will return the first array. I tried the foreach to retrieve all information. in other posts i look it seems not necessary to place the number of array when looping.. thats what I read, probably wrong.